# How to use java heap profilers (HPROF)

Tags: java, hprof

With the basic knowledge of java 'hprof', I tried executing the below command as per oracle docs

```
java -agentlib:hprof Hello.class
```

But i get the below error instead of the profiling information

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Hello.class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
```

Can someone illustrate on how should hprof be used properly so as to get the profiling information ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove the `.class` at the end of the class as `Java` by default will search for `class` files.

```
java -agentlib:hprof Hello
```

However, to get the heap allocation profile you need to add some parameters...

```
java -agentlib:hprof=heap=sites Hello
```

For more information type

```
java -agentlib:hprof=help
```

And visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.html

Comment: I tried running the command for classes located in other folders. I get the same exception along with the message 'Could not find the main class'. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @aarish When running a `java` program, you can only call the Main file (the one which contains the `main` method). This is why you get this error.

Comment: The java program contains the main method

Comment: @aarish then make sure you typed it correctly and that the main method declaration is `public static void main(String args[])`